# Importing Data from SQL in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

When Importing Data from SQL into an excel sheet, is there any way of importing it just to one specific cell. By default, whenever you import from SQL you have to put it into a table. My SQL query only returns a top result of dates, so the table would have only one row/column.

I have tried to convert it to range, but it'll remove the connection to the database if I do that.

Comment: Can you just point the one data point returned from the sql query to another cell?

Comment: In a nutshell, my question is asking. How do you "point" to just one cell instead of having it point to a whole table by default.

Comment: If you're willing to take the VBA route then this is quite possible. You can even create a UDF for that. Yet, the performance will drop significantly as the slowest part in getting data from an SQL is always connecting to the SQL. If you pull (for example) with 100 UDFs 100 value then VBA will connect 100 times to the SQL and disconnect again. If you get the data in bulks it is extremely performant and you can place the results with VBA wherever you want. Alternatively, I'd stick with @dfundako suggestion.